# Normal Map Works in Eevee But Not in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, normal-map

I'm working through the Blender Guru's donut tutorial and I'm at the point I want to apply a normal map to the wall.  I've tried to duplicate every step in the tutorial but the texture does not render if my Render Engine is set to Cycles:

[image]
https://imgur.com/a/GBAMUsc

it only shows when my Render Engine is set to Eevee:

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend) and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I've uploaded it here:https://pasteall.org/blend/9c992df5c55644cabab63d73a6abbaf2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scale is a bit crazy, apply it and it will work fine (not sure why it works fine in Eevee though):

[image]